# Compare JSON tree items with arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, tree

I have the following example of tree structure:

```
const tree = {
  units: [
    {
      id: 482,
      units: [
        {
          id: 483,
        },
      ],
      entities: [
        {
          id: 318,
          portfolios: [
            {
              id: 356,
            },
            {
              id: 357,
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 319,
          portfolios: [
            {
              id: 358,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

and the following arrays of objects:

```
const units = [
      {
        id: 483
      },
    ];
const entities = [
  {
        id: 319
      },
];
const portfolios = [
  {
        id: 358
      },
];
```

I need to find a way to parse the whole tree with all the 3 arrays (units, entities, portfolios) and if the id of an item from the arrays matches to one id from inside the tree, I should add a flag (e.g found = true).

After this parsing function, I want the output to look like this:

```
 const tree = {
  units: [
    {
      id: 482,
      units: [
        {
          id: 483,
          found: true
        },
      ],
      entities: [
        {
          id: 318,
          portfolios: [
            {
              id: 356,
            },
            {
              id: 357,
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 319,
          found: true,
          portfolios: [
            {
              id: 358,
              found: true,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

Could anyone please advise me on the best solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursion function to update the structure in place:

```js
const tree = {units: [{id: 482, units: [{id: 483,},], entities: [{id: 318, portfolios: [{id: 356,},{id: 357,},],},{id: 319, portfolios: [{id: 358,},],},],},],};
const units = [{id: 483},];
const entities = [{id: 319},];
const portfolios = [{id: 358},];
var vals = {units:units, entities:entities, portfolios:portfolios};
function update_tree(d, parent = null){
   if (d.constructor === Array){
      for (var i of d){
         update_tree(i, parent = parent)
      }
   }
   else if (d.constructor === Object){
      if (parent != null && parent in vals){
         if (vals[parent].some(function(x){return Object.keys(x).some(function(y){return y in d && d[y] === x[y]})})){
            d['found'] = true;
         }
      }
      for (var i of Object.keys(d)){
         update_tree(d[i], parent = i)
      }
   }
}
update_tree(tree)
console.log(tree)
```